# Learning Japanese alphabet

Tags: kanji, katakana, hiragana

Konbanwa,

I just started learning about Japanese alphabets, and I started with Hiragana, so **is it right to start with Hiragana then Katana?** and if I learned about the both writing systems **which one should I use in my writing?** and my last question is **when to start learning about Kanji ?**

Comment: I rather hope you mean katakana. Swords are not for writing!

Comment: 1) Yes, katakana is secondary in importance and can be postponed by a few months 2) The one that's appropriate for the word 3) As soon as you are confident with your katakana (can read without errors)

Comment: @Nothingatall yeah I always think that katakana is katana xD, because I hear katana a lot in animes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, that's absolutely right. Learn hiragana first to get used to the pronunciation, then switch to katakana.
2. Use hiragana (and later kanji) to write most Japanese, but use katakana when you need to write loan words such as "toilet"
3. I recommend you to learn kanji as early as possible. You will really need it in order to read Japanese.